# Vue.js: Setting div position and size using scoped CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm working on a web application using Vue.js that has the following structure:

```
<App>
    <HomePage>
        <ErrorPage/>
        <StartPage/>
        <ExitPage/>
    </HomePage>

    <Game>
        <GameScreen/>
    </Game> 
</App>
```

`<HomePage>` and `<Game>` are going to be conditionally rendered and will not be visible at the same time. The same applies also for their child components.

Now I would like the currently displayed child component (or the root `<div>` of the child component) to fill the whole browser window. So for example `<ErrorPage/>` or `<GameScreen/>` should be stretched to full size.

I've been trying all kinds of combinations using `position: absolute`, `width`, `height` etc., but still the child components only take up a small part of the window. This has probably something to do with the way `<style scoped>` works in Vue.js, because in an old prototype of my application (which didn't use Vue.js) things worked fine. But just removing the `scoped` attribute doesn't help.

Does anyone have an idea where to place the right CSS to make things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
.game-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Replace `.game-div` with the selector for your `<Game>` element.